# How do I pin point which processes consuming the CPU from resource monitor?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, cpu-usage

I need help on pin pointing which processes actually utilizing the most CPU on my server.
I had a Win2008 server which are hosting several applications. From time to time the CPU will spike to 100%, when I check from the resource monitor I find that the CPU utilization for individual processes isn't that high but the overall CPU usage is high.

[image: Please refer this screencap]

Comment: You are looking at it. When you sum up these CPU usages of the separate process you have the overall usage. What else do you want?

Comment: How do I explain it to my application guys when they ask why does the particular processes uses only 12% of cpu considered as culprit for high CPU usage?

Comment: This is not a single process that uses 12%. There are four processes of the same service, three with 12% and one with 11%, which accumulates to 47% out of the currently used 69% (at the point the screenshot is taken). We don't know what this services does, if it is heavy on IO it could also be responsible for a part of the 12% of the System CPU usage.

Comment: Noted Gerald. I got confuse as on how it suppose to be high when the utilization of each processes is only 12%, being used to seeing normally a single processes using up high CPU on my laptop, thus I thought i'm expected to see the same scenario. Anyway, is there any tools out there that can dig deeper to see how much the processes is utilizing per CPU core?